# Grant Anonymous Access to Lists/Libraries at Office 365

Tags: list, office-365, anonymous-authentication, access, libraries

Is there some way I could grant anonymous access on a public sharepoint site?

I know that most of you would say that I just had to set this website to online (he is still set as offline), but my question is if I can enable anonymous access even though it is offline.

I saw a few solutions on the web but none of them worked.

1. http://anonymous365.codeplex.com/
2. http://www.xenoxgaravito.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=8

So here is my problem...

I have a custom list on Office 365 and I wanted anonymous users to have access to this list without require them to log in. But if I try to access this list to include or view items through public site address, Office 365 requires me to provide an user and password. I tried to make the same thing with site pages but with no success too.

So I am guessing that is really impossible to accomplish with Office 365
I did that easily when I was working with On Premise.

Answer (score 2):

You can grant anonymous access to anyone with a guest link for a specific **document**. [Documentation here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232).

As for folders and entire lists it is not possible in SharePoint Online:

1. [Link 1](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/214014.aspx)
2. [Link 2](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/266324.aspx)

Nor for the site collections:

- [SharePoint Online office 365, Can we have multiple site collections
  with anonymous access enabled](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100799/sharepoint-online-office-365-can-we-have-multiple-site-collections-with-anonymo?rq=1)

The only OOTB way is to know these people's email addresses and they need to have Live IDs. Then you could share the list by emailing them.

Comment: This solution would be great, if it were a small thing, for a small number of users for access. The problem is that it should work as a "talk to us" page and just for this purpose that I wanted to enable anonymous access, to let a huge number of users access it.

I guess the properly solution would be making the entire public site "Online", so those anonymous users could access this specific page.

Answer (score 0):

The Anonymous Access Permisionnator webpart that I made still works with O365, but you need to make sure to increase your resource quota to a non-zero number.

This doesn't seem to be possible with a non-enterprise tenant, but if you have one, give it a try.  [I wrote about it here](http://www.xenox.net/2015/01/31/anonymous-access-sharepoint-public-website-office-365/).